# .conf not found via php

Tags: php, linux

I am trying to read a a .conf file under /var/www/myDir on linux.

This is the code

```
$confFile = "vhost.conf";
if (file_exists($confFile)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

It says file not found.  Any ideas why>

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the full path

```
$confFile = "/var/www/myDir/vhost.conf";
```

Comment: @Jean: hummm.. How you are getting _not found_ message it should be either `The file <filename> exists` or `The file <filename> does not exists`

Answer (score 1):

is your script executed in the same Path? otherwise try using the full path

```
if (file_exists('/var/www/myDir'. $confFile)) {
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute paths, like this:

```
$confFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/vhost.conf";
if (file_exists($confFile)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

Or maybe this:

```
$confFile = "/var/www/myDir/vhost.conf";
if (file_exists($confFile)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

Comment: Dammit! Try giving your `myDir` global read/write permissions for testing purpose? If that works, try different combinations of permissions to get you the security and functionality you need. It's a long shot, but it might work :-)